# How to perform multiple if condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this excel function where it says:

```
=IF(id ="pre_stage";"a";IF(id="static";"b";"c"))
```

I tried to implement this in my python script to create a new column.

```
df['type'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: 'a' if x == 'pre_stage' else 'b')
```

I miss to put the second condition, where if the 'id' is 'static' then the type should be 'b', and other will be 'c'.

How is the script supposed to write?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping and use [**`pd.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) here.

```
mapping = {"pre_stage": "a", "static": "b"}
df["type"] = df["id"].map(mapping).fillna("c")
```

You can use [**`np.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) here.

```
condlist = [df["id"].eq("pre_stage"), df["id"].eq("static")]
choicelist = ["a", "b"]
df["type"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, "c")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a lambda, you can pass in a function to `apply`:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 'pre_stage':
        return 'a'
    elif x == 'static':
        return 'b'
    return 'c'

df['type'] = df['id'].apply(f)
```

You can also use a dictionary:

```
d = {'pre_stage': 'a', 'static': 'b'}
df['type'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: d.get(x, 'c'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions are going to be nested, its better to define a function for it. It also helps to make your code clearer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['pre-stage','static','not-related']})

def func(x):
    if x == 'pre-stage':
        return 'a'
    elif x == 'static':
        return 'b'
    return 'c'
```

Result:

```
df['type'].apply(func) #as example, you can assign it to the frame as you did

>>
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: type, dtype: object
```